# ViewModel has no zero argument constructor at java.lang.Class.newInstance

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

Note: Before marking as duplicate, please read carefully. I have tried all the existing answers.

I'm using dagger2.

View Model instance is successfully created in the activity, but when I'm opening a BottomSheetDialog from the same activity then unable to create the instance.

```
private val searchViewModel: SearchViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

Logs:

> ui.search.viewmodel.SearchViewModel> has no zero argument constructor
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$NewInstanceFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:219)
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:278) 
> at androidx.lifecycle.SavedStateViewModelFactory.create(SavedStateViewModelFactory.java:106) 
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:185) 
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:150) 
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:54) 
> at androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelLazy.getValue(ViewModelProvider.kt:41)

Comment: How are you verifying that it was "successfully created in the activity"? What does your SearchViewModel's constructor look like?

Comment: I'm using that ViewModel, to get the data, then no crash

Comment: You're not passing any factory to `by activityViewModels()`. Where are you defining your custom View model Factory?

Comment: @ianhanniballake you are correct, I'm missing this

Answer (score 0):

In dagger 2, whenever we created **Shared viewmodel**, than we have to write the factory like this:

```
@Provides
fun providesSearchViewModel(
    activity: SearchActivity,
    factory: ViewModelProvider.Factory
): SearchViewModel {
    return ViewModelProvider(activity, factory).get(SearchViewModel::class.java)
}
```